# How to show search result in a TableView as drop down a TextField in JavaFX?

Tags: java, search, javafx, combobox, textfield

I need to search something in textfield, the result should show as dropdown in the same text field inside a tableview.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow,  you may need to share more details and the specific problem with related code

Comment: Use a [`PopupWindow`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/PopupWindow.html) (look at the subclasses).

Comment: I think you mean something like this from contrsFX http://fxexperience.com/2016/03/introducing-the-controlsfx-tablefilter/

Answer (score 1):

Regarding autocompletion: You can use a TextField and add an AutoComplete binding using [ControlsFX TextFields](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.html):

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, "Paris", "Rome", "Amsterdam");
```

I couldn't understand what you meant by "inside a tableview".

Comment: I think he wants to filter the tableview with the Textfield input

Comment: If that's the case, he can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181146/javafx-tableview-filter-using-textfield) question.

Comment: Actually what I need is  search and fetch a person data into a text field. The text field is used to search the person by name, contact number, register number. when I start typing, it will search in database and show the result as drop down menu from text field. And this drop down menu contain RegNo, Name, Mobile Number as a Table View.
When I select a row in table view, it fill fetch reg no to the searched textfield.

Comment: Unfortunately, ControlsFX's `AutoCompletionBinding<T>` allows you only to provide a `StringConverter<T>` not a cell factory where you can add a `TableView<T>` as a graphical node. The implementation of `AutoCompletionBinding<T>` uses an `AutoCompletePopup<T>` which is basically a [PopupControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html). So I believe if you want more than a textual list, ControlsFX is not the solution.

Comment: An easy solution could be like this: use an editable `ComboBox`, you can put the `TableView` as the graphic of the `ComboBox` by providing a cell factory. Change the items of that `ComboBox` when the user starts typing by fetching the new items from a database. You need to handle stuff like showing the items of the `ComboBox` when the user starts typing and hide them when the user leaves.